# Showing that a certain formula of second order logic with full semantic is true in all and only non-standard model of arithmetic.

Tags: logic, model-theory

Showing that a certain formula of second order logic with full semantic is true in all and only non-standard model of arithmetic.

$\exists X(\exists x Xx \wedge \forall x\forall y((Xx \wedge (x=0 \vee x=y+1)) \rightarrow (x\not=y \wedge Xy)))$

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: First of all, I'd check very carefully that you've written it down correctly: it looks very suspicious that you can conclude $x \neq y$ from an assumption that doesn't depend on $y$ when $x = 0$.

Comment: @Rob There is really something fishy going on there, and yes I triple checked it and it is exactly what they asked me to do.. I agree with you that it is strange but I think that is part of the reason why it must be true only in non-standard model. Hence it must be true only because there are non-standard numbers... (ps. if x=0 then y is not its predecessor)

Comment: Please remember that the title of a post is not part of the post - the post itself should state a clear question independent of the title. A deeper issue with the question here is that there are no nonstandard models of arithmetic in second-order logic with full semantics.

Comment: @Carl I don't think that what you are saying is right. Only in full semantics we have non-standard model, whence in Henkin semantic you don't have any non-standard model.

Comment: @SpikeSpiegel - That doesn't seem right. It's well known that second order PA is categorical assuming standards semantics, whereas it's also well known that second order logic with Henkin semantics is roughly equivalent to first-order logic (by Lindström's theorems). So it'd seem that there's no way to have a non-standard model with full standard semantics.

Comment: @Spike Spiegel: what you wrote in your last comment is the opposite of the actual situation.

Comment: But then what kind of exercises did they give to me??? :(
I don't know what to say! I can show that, assuming a standard model, I can falsify the formula, because if x is not 0, then every predecessor of x has the property X, but then you arrive at the case when x=0, then the antecedent is true and the consequent is false, having 0 \not = 0. What is this showing then? Given the categoricity of PA2? Please somebody help me.. I am really lost on this..

Comment: Although second-order logic with full semantics axiomatizes arithmetic categorically, the English part of the question seems meaningful.  Any first-order structure obviously determines a corresponding full second-order structure, so as to make sense of satisfaction of first-order structures by second order formulas.  Now, the problem gives some second-order formula $\phi$ and asks for proof that $\mathcal A\models \phi$ iff $\mathcal A$ satisfies the first-order Peano Axioms but isn't isomorphic to a standard model of arithmetic.

Comment: @mmw Thanks man!!

Answer (score -1):

This should be the right answer to the question.

Suppose that the formula is true in an arbitrarily standard model $M$, then we get that there is a property $X$, such that if there is an $x$ that has that property, for every number, if $Xx$ and $x\not=0$ then also the predecessor of $x$, namely $y$ has the property $X$. Now we can iterate this reasoning, given that $Xy$ and the if $y\not=0$ then also the predecessor of $y$ has the property $X$, until we get to the case in which $x=0$. In this case the antecedent of the implication would be true, given that the left disjunct in the antecedent is true, but the consequent would be false having $0\not=0$. This is so because we know that if the successor of 0 has the property X, then also 0 must have the property X. Also we have $\forall y$ in the formula, hence we will have the case in which $y=0$. Therefore we get the implication false, and this contradicts our assumption. By the arbitrariness of the standard model $M$ we can conclude that the formula has no standard model.

Now if we assume that the formula is true in a full semantic model, then we get that it must exists a set of all the non-standard numbers, given that the interpretation of $X$ range over all the possible subsets of the power set of the domain. That is our property $X$. So it is clear that the formula must be true for all the non-standard numbers. This is so because whenever we pick a non-standard number $n^*$, it must have a predecessor, say $n_{i}^*$ (because that non-standard number cannot be 0). Now given that every successor of a standard number is standard, it follows that also $n_{i}^*$ is non-standard. By applying this reasoning over and over we get an infinite descending sequence of non-standard numbers. By a very similar reasoning this allows us to say that the formula is valid in such a model. Whenever $x$ has the property $X$ ($x$ is a non standard number), we can always find a predecessor with the property of being non-standard without ever coming to a stop. Now by arbitrariness of the model, we have that (given that no standard model satisfy the formula), the formula is true in all and only non standard models.